# How do I join 2 tables and search for 2 conditions including a SUM

Tags: sql

I have two tables, and two conditions that I am trying to write a query for.

I need to join the two following tables:

1. trans
2. transunit

They are joined by the *accountID* field which is in both tables, I also want the *clientID* which is in the trans table.

Secondly I also need for the field *allocated* in trans table to be '%Y', and I need the sum of the *units* field for each accountID in transunit to be greater than 0.

I can join the two tables, but i'm struggling with using the two conditions to filter the data.

The only columns I would like to return from the 2 tables is:

1. accountID
2. clientID
3. SUM(units)

Here's what I have so far...

```
select  trans.accountID,trans.clientID from  
inner join transUnit 
on trans.AccountID = transUnit.accountID
where trans.IsAllocated like '%Y%'
```

This joins the two tables, and uses 1 condition.

I have the 2nd query which sums all records in transunits table by accountID. 1 account ID can have multiple units records. I am just looking for accountID which have SUM greater than 0.

```
select count(*), sum(units) as Sumunits,accountid from transunit
group by accountid
```

Now the tricky part, how do I join these two queries together, and filter so that I only display when SUM is greater than 0.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: To filter on aggregates, the `having clause` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description it sounds like you want a `having` clause. A `having` clause sort of acts like a `where` clause on the groups made by the `group by` statement, and limits the groups returned:

```
SELECT trans.accountID, trans.clientID, SUM(units) AS Sum_of_Units
FROM trans
INNER JOIN transUnit ON trans.AccountID = transUnit.accountID 
WHERE trans.IsAllocated LIKE '%Y%'
GROUP BY trans.accountid, trans.clientid
HAVING SUM(units) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To do aggregations you'll need a GROUP BY clause.
To evaluate by an aggregation you'll need a HAVING clause.
Something like this, perhaps:

```
select trans.accountID,trans.clientID, SUM(transunits.units)
from trans inner join transUnit on trans.AccountID = transUnit.accountID
where trans.IsAllocated like '%Y%'
GROUP BY trans.accountID,trans.clientID
HAVING SUM(transunits.units) > 0
```

I don't think you'd need to inline this one, but in case I've misunderstood here's how you could do that:

```
select trans.accountID,trans.clientID, q.Sumunits from trans
inner join
(select accountid, sum(units) as Sumunits,
 from transunit
 group by accountid) AS q ON trans.AccountID = q.accountID
where trans.IsAllocated like '%Y%' AND q.Sumunits > 0
```

Comment: I tried the former query, and it worked great. Cheers